# ajax envia variable undefined a app.js (usando nodejs)

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs

este es mi codigo, para enviar la variable "copiando", pero solo muestra por consola undefined

```
    var texto="no existe 1 rayo zapato zanahorea karaoke Whisky software wikipedia jinete japon jabon facil frio rayo yogur habil hablar galleta gigante gentil valiente vehiculo vegetariano quebrado quemado botella bandido brazil baile patata patria palabra marcial maqueta manantial caballero temperatura tercero ubicar urgente delfin delgado danza lectura laboratorio ilusivo inadvertencia ilimitado nacido narrado racionalidad radiactivo racismo satelite septiembre obstruir oscilatorio elogioso embajada emblema abundancia kiwi";
    var copiando;


        $(function () {
            var captureInput = $('.clickme');
            $(captureInput).focus();
                $(captureInput).keyup(function(event){

                    startUPDOWN= (new Date()).getTime();
                    if (!is_special_key(event.keyCode)) {
                        var delta= startUPDOWN - startPressUP;

                        copiando=delta;
                        key_cadaTecla.push(new claves(event.keyCode,tiempoPulsacion));

                        document.getElementById("keyCadaTecla").innerHTML = "tiempo de cada tecla:  ";
                        for (var i = 0; i < key_cadaTecla.length; i++) {
                                var result=document.createTextNode("("+key_cadaTecla[i].id+" "+key_cadaTecla[i].time+")");
                                document.getElementById("keyCadaTecla").appendChild(result);
                            };
                        document.getElementById("ult").innerHTML = "tiempo de Press a Up:   " + delta ;
                        teclaActual=event.keyCode;
                    };  
                    tiempoPulsacion=0;
                }); 
        });


$(window).on('load', function() {           

    var id = 'idUsuario';
    $('#add-new-fact').click(function() {
    var fact = $('#new-fact').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/servidor",
      data: { fact: copiando},
     // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        alert("si");
        $('<li>').appendTo('#facts').text(fact);
        $('#new-fact').val('');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        var msg = 'Status: ' + err.status + ': ' + err.responseText;

        document.open("text/html", "replace");
        document.write(err.responseText);
        document.close();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la variable tiene el valor `undefined` quiere decir que **nunca se ha actualizado su valor** desde que la declararse. Por ende, se deduce que hay algo erróneo dentro del `keyup`.

Te recomiendo ir viendo el valor de `copiando` en el transcurso del evento.

Comment: si mando una cadena funciona, me explico cuando copiando es un string funciona, pero cuando lo vuelvo array sale "undefined", como lo solucionaria?

Comment: Primero, deberías explicar qué es lo que hace tu código, aunque deduzco que es el tiempo de cada pulsación. Bien, como `delta` es un número entonces `copiando` lo es también, dado que le asignas su valor. Ahora, bajo qué circunstancias el valor de `copiando` es un string o array?

Comment: si efectivamente es el tiempo de tecleo, ahora lo vuelvo array solo para probar si funciona !!! arriba declaro var copiando=[];  y  en vez de copiando=delta; lo modifique asi: copiando.push(delta);

Comment: Es correcto. Para agregar un elemento a un array se usa el método push.

Comment: me olvide comentar que el resultado es 'undefined'

Comment: cual seria el error, por que cuando es un string funciona, y porque no funciona cuando es un array?

Comment: Ninguno, no hay razón programática para ello. JavaScript es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, es decir, una variable no tiene un tipo de dato durante todo su ciclo de vida, puede tener un string y luego un array y tomaría el valor. El asunto es, ¿bajo qué **circunstancias** lo conviertes a Array? ¿Puedes anexar el código en donde conviertes? Así mismo, como está ahora tu código, la **única** razón por la que `copiando` es `undefined` es porque **nunca se ejecuta** el if en donde le pasas el valor de `delta` a `copiando`.

Comment: el codigo hice lo puse abajo

Comment: para solucionarlo tuve que serializarlo { fact: JSON.stringify(copiando)}

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, colega @rn3w. La función `JSON.stringify` lo que haces es convertir un array u objeto ({}) a string para que pueda ser enviada en la petición (en una petición sólo hay básicamente strings). No te llegué a entender, pensé que el `undefined` lo tenías en el cliente y no en node.js ;). Un saludo, y cuando tengas otra duda, ya sabes que estamos para ayudar.